# Cycle Divs of text with images

Tags: text, transition, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to sync up my image slides with their textblocks. I've found that Cycle 2 is a great jQuery plug-in and a simple code got me quite far. There's one issue, however. Whenever the text slides for the first time the transition is really bad. The letters of the current and next block "morph" into eachother for a second. After the first cycle everything works as it should.

Here's the cycle code:

```
$("#slideshow").cycle({
timeout:0, // no autoplay
fx: 'scrollHorz',
randomizeEffects: false, 
next: '#next',
prev: '#prev',
});

$("#text").cycle({
timeout:0, // no autoplay
fx: 'scrollHorz',
next: '#next',
prev: '#prev',
});
```

U can see everything in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucb792/85TCZ/1/ (just click arrow left or right)

Is this something that can be fixed, or do I need to search for other solutions to make something like this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin is changing the width of the text the first time you use the prev/next controls.  Instead of setting the width to the `#text`, set the width to the `divs` inside `#text` slideshow.  Changing the CSS to this fixed it for me:

```
#text div{
    width:600px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbernar1/85TCZ/3/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but thanks a lot!. Such a simple solution, I just couldn't find it... Works like a charm now!